# SO/SF/SU goals: community wiki distinction?

Tags: discussion, reputation, community-wiki

I got into a [discussion on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/8077/how-do-i-set-up-ssh-so-i-dont-have-to-type-my-password/8078#8078) about the goals of the system and the types of answers that work best. One of the comments was this:

> One of the reasons for Superuser is to build a encyclopedic collection of common questions and answers. Links to other sites don't advance that goal.

Super User's about page says this:

> Super User is **collaboratively built and maintained** by your fellow users. Once the system learns to trust you, you'll be able to edit anything, much like [Wikipedia](http://wikipedia.org/). With your help, we can build good answers to every question a power user might have.

Considering these two quotes, my question is **why distinguish between community wiki and regular questions?** There's a requirement of 750 reputation to edit CW questions, and 2000 to edit other people's questions, and CW questions don't generate reputation. Instead, why don't we just **make all posts CW, and up/down-vote *individual edits***, with both the question votes and the edit votes generating reputation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because then it is not a Q&A site and just another wikipedia. The concept of CW is for discussion subject and opinion polls. We are discussing this at length in another thread [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/help-define-superuser-com)